# How to implement Lazy Json to load 10 records from json response to uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new on this topic (Lazy Json), but I have read somewhere that Lazy Json is used to load data from json response to an application, but i have never implemented one.
I want to load 10 records from my json response to my UITableView and after these 10 records load another 10 and so on for all records.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Process the json data asynchronously, and retrieve the actual data for the first 10 records and when this is done, dispatch a `[self.tableView reloadData]` back to the main queue.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer but actually i'm new on this topic so can you please post some implementation code here?  That will really appreciated..